# Как устранить проблему с отображением модального окна (popup) при нажатии кнопок обновления или возвращения назад

Tags: html, css, popup, modal

проблема с отображением модального окна (popup), а именно:
1) Если перейти по ссылке с модального окна, а потом вернуться через кнопку браузера назад, то возвращаясь на страницу мы увидим пустое модальное окно.
2) Если когда модальное окно открыто, нажать обновить (браузерное), то форма опять же таки станет пустой.

Как сделать так, чтобы форма пропадала при обновлении и не появлялась, после возвращения на страничку? Большое спасибо.

Чтобы было более понятно, вот видео, как выглядит проблема:
https://youtu.be/vZROqM37F7k

```css
.popup {   
   position: fixed;
   padding: 10px;
   max-width: 500px;
   border-radius: 0.5em;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   color: #000;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
   z-index: 1;
}
.popup:target {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   transition-delay: 0s;
}
.popup .close {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   top: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #000;
   transition: color .3s;
   font-size: 2em;
   line-height: 1.5;
   font-weight: 700;
}
.popup .close:hover {
   color: #f00;
}
.close-popup {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   cursor: default;
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   transition: opacity .5s, visibility 0s linear .5s;
}
.popup:target + .close-popup {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   transition-delay: 0s;
}

.content button{ 
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff0e6;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4facfe 0%, #00f2fe 100%);
}
.content button:hover{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00f2fe 0%, #4facfe 100%);
}


.block-post {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: #404F56;
  box-shadow: 0 1.4rem 8rem rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.block-post__img {
  min-width: 35rem;
  max-width: 35rem;
  height: 30rem;
  transform: translateX(-8rem);
  position: relative;
}

.block-post__img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  border-radius: .8rem;
}

.block-post__img::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(28, 24, 24, 0.8), rgba(128, 134, 116, 0.8));
  box-shadow: .5rem .5rem 3rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  border-radius: .8rem;
}
.block-post__date span {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: .5rem 0;
}

.block-post__title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #6d757b;
}

.block-post__text {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.block-post__cta {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(28, 24, 24, 0.8), rgba(128, 134, 116, 0.8) 100%);
  border-radius: .8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="turtleFacts">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Тесты</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="turtle in list.dataJ | filter:list.search"> 
                              <div class="block-post">
                                  <div class="block-post__img">
                                      <img ng-src="{{turtle.image_urlJ}}">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="block-post__info">
                                      <div class="block-post__date">
                                          <span>...</span>
                                          <span>...</span>
                                      </div>
                                      <h1 class="block-post__title">...</h1>
                                      <p class="block-post__text">...</p>
                                      <a href="#popupW" ng-click="list.changeActiveTurtle(turtle)" class="btn block-post__cta">Узнать подробнее</a> 
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>    
                    <div id="popupW" class="popup">
                        <a href="mytests.php" class="close">&times;</a>
                        <h2>Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст</h2>
                        <p>Текст Текст Текст </p>
                        <div id="turtle-info" class="content content-1">
                            <form action="mytests.php">
                                <button type="submit">Текст Текст!</button>
                            </form>
                            <form action="test3.php">
                                <button type="submit">Текст!</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При такой реализации модального окна вы не избавитесь от этой проблемы.

Можно реализовать через js/jQuery на show() и hide()

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал, теперь все хорошо) Извиняюсь за задержку)